# Android recommender system - compute recommendations locally or on a server

Tags: android, recommendation-engine

I want to develop a movie recommendation engine in Android, but I am not sure whether I should store the data locally on the Android device and calculate the recommendations here or do it on a web service.

Comment: What data would you like to store? How would you like to calculate recommendations?

Comment: I am using context-based recommendation technique, so I want to calculate the dissimilarity matrix between the movies. I am not sure whether I should do this on Android phone, or using a web service

Answer (score 0):

I think this idea would work best with a web service, although in the end I imagine some data would end up being stored locally for offline access. With a web service you will have a lot more flexibility in terms of expanding and adding features.

Comment: Thanks. I don't really know much about web services, could you tell me the steps/technologies needed to develop them?

Comment: The ones that I know of are Parse.com, Microsoft Azure, Amazon AWS and  Google Cloud Platform. I only have experience with Parse.com though, so you will have to determine which one best suits your needs. I think it's possible for you to store the data using a web service and handle the logic on the device.